# CSS -> Conteúdo da DIV sobre o content do ::after

Tags: css, css3

no site que estou tentando desenvolver,

https://fielcard.net.br/

lá no meio tem uma **seção** de **dúvidas frequentes** e tenho a seguinte **estrutura**:

```js
$( 'body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article' ).click( function () {

 $( 'body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article' ).not( this ).find( "header" ).removeClass( "ativo" );

 $( 'body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article' ).find( "p" ).hide();

 $( this ).find( 'header' ).removeClass( 'ativo' ).toggleClass( 'ativo' );

 if ( !$( this ).find( 'p' ).is( ':visible' ) ) { 

  $( this ).find( 'header' ).addClass( 'ativo' );
  $( this ).find( 'p' ).slideToggle( "slow" );

 } else {

  $( this ).find( 'header' ).removeClass( 'ativo' );
  $( this ).find( 'p' ).slideToggle( "slow" );

 }

  }

)
```

```css
body div#duvidas > section.duvidas {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 60%;
}
body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article {
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
    border-color: #1b3665;
    border-style: solid;
}
body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header:hover,
body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header:active{
 color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b3665;
}
body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1b3665;
}
body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > p {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header {
 position: relative;
 color: #1b3665;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bolder;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 35px 10px 10px;
}
body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header::after {
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 right: 5px;
 top: 0;
 content: '+';
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: auto 0;
}
body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header::after {
    content: '+';
}
body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header.ativo {
    color: green;
}
body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header.ativo::after {
    content: '-';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <body>
      <div id=duvidas>
        <section class=duvidas>
          <article>
            <header>Este Título é grande de mais para caber nesse header você não acha?</header>
            <p>Texto</p>
          </article>
        </section>
      </div>
    </body>
```

No **header**, eu tenho um `::after`

Mas estou com um **problema** que não estou conseguindo resolver:

O texto dos **títulos**, quando em **versão móbile**, acabam *subindo* sobre o **conteúdo** do `::after`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue o código corrigido abaixo, espero que ajude :)

```css
body div#duvidas > section.duvidas {
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 60%;
    }
    body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article {
        border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
        border-color: #1b3665;
        border-style: solid;
    }
    body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header:hover,
    body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header:active{
     color: #fff;
        background-color: #1b3665;
    }
    body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article:last-of-type {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #1b3665;
    }
    body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > p {
        display: none;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header {
     position: relative;
     color: #1b3665;
     font-size: 1.5em;
     font-weight: bolder;
     cursor: pointer;
     padding: 10px 35px 10px 10px;
    }
    body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header::after {
     position: absolute;
     display: inline-block;
     right: 5px;
     top: 0;
     content: '+';
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
     line-height: 30px;
     text-align: center;
     bottom: 0;
     margin: auto 0;
    }
    body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header::after {
        content: '+';
    }
    body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header.ativo {
        background: #1b3665;
        color: #fff;
    }
    body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header.ativo::after {
        content: '-';
    }
```

```html
<div id=duvidas>
     <section class=duvidas>
      <article>
       <header>Este Título é grande de mais para caber nesse header você não acha?</header>
       <p>Texto</p>
      </article>
      <article>
       <header>Este Título é grande de mais para caber nesse header você não acha?</header>
       <p>Texto</p>
      </article>
      <article>
       <header>Este Título é grande de mais para caber nesse header você não acha?</header>
       <p>Texto</p>
      </article>
     </section>
    </div>
```

As modificações foram feitas em:

> body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header

E

> body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header::after

Um bom ajuste pro jQuery das suas tabs é o seguinte: (Está comentado)

```
$( 'body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article' ).on('click', function () {
  // Verifica se a tab atual está aberta, se sim, fecha, se não, fecha todas abertas e abre
  if ( $(this).find( 'header' ).hasClass('ativo') ) {
    // Pra garantir, fecha todas as abas abertas
    $( this ).find( 'header' ).removeClass( 'ativo' );
    $( this ).find( 'p' ).slideUp();
  } else {
    // Fecha todas as tabs anteriores e remove as classes ativo deles
    $( 'section.duvidas > article' ).find( 'header' ).removeClass( 'ativo' );
    $( 'section.duvidas > article' ).find( 'p' ).slideUp();
    // Adiciona a classe ativo no header atual e abre a tag p
    $( this ).find( 'header' ).addClass( 'ativo' );
    $( this ).find( 'p' ).slideDown();
  }
});
```

Comment: Deixa eu te perguntar uma coisa: Achei bacana a sua solução. Nela, nas telas de celular, ao fazer o mousover e apos clicado, o titulo clicado continua com a cor Azul de fundo. Mas nos dektops após a retirada do mouse a cor branca volta. Como adaptar isso aos desktops tb?

Comment: @CarlosRocha Modificação feita, faça bom uso :)

Comment: isso eu já havia testado. Mas isso apenas deixa as outros 'p' abertos e não altera adiciono o efeito ao fechar. Se possível, refaz a resposta com essas informações que está passando fazendo favor? Estou apagando comentários anteriores a esse.

Comment: @CarlosRocha Adicionei o script corrigido das abas no final da pergunta, basicamente, você vai remover aquele seu jquery e vai colocar esse ai por cima, eu testei e funcionou tudo certinho aqui

Comment: Agora seu certo! Olham desculpe o meu incômodo, mas muito obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

É só dar um `padding-right: 70px;` na classe `body div#duvidas > section.duvidas > article > header { }`

Vai ficar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Novamente falta de atenção minha né?

Comment: @CarlosRocha como já te falei algumas vezes... vc está pecando com coisas básicas... Tem que saber a diferença entre padding e margin, saber quando usar um ou outro etc. Vc encontra no youtube uma infinidade de aulas em português sobre isso, aproveite e veja também algumas aulas sobre position e display. vc não vai gastar 2 horas com isso e vai aprender pro resto da vida. Fica a dica

Comment: O meu caso é mais grave: Saber eu sei. Mas está faltando é atenção mesmo! Como eu trabalho sozinho, faço tudo, back, dados e front. Às vezes acabo me atrapalhando um pouco (?) e ficando perdido!

Comment: @CarlosRocha vdd as vezes da um branco de coisas básicas e acabamos tomando o caminho mais difícil quando na realidade é mais fácil do que a gente imagina